# how i can retrive the passed data from UploadStringTaskAsync call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, webclient

I have the following webclient :-

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
   {

 var url = currentURL+ "home/scanserver";
 wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
 var json =wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(url, "FQDN=allscan");
   }
```

now i am passing a security token & a data named FQDN. so on the receiver Post action method i am unable to retrieve the FQDN parameter,

i tried the following but did not work

```
string FQDN = Request.Form["FQDN"];
```

also I tried defining the FQDN inside the action method parameter as follow:- `public async Task<ActionResult> ScanServer(string FQDN)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If FQDN is a `query parameter` then try

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
  var url = currentURL+ "home/scanserver?FQDN=allscan";
  wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
  var json =wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(url, "");
}
```

**EDIT**

To post as a form use the [UploadValuesTaskAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh472354(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
var url = currentURL+ "home/scanserver";
var args = new NameValueCollection { { "FQDN", "allscan" } };
var json = wc.UploadValuesTaskAsync(url, args);
```

`json` is now a `Task<byte>` not a `Task<string>`, so you must convert it into a `string`; something like

```
var s = Encoding.Utf8.GetString(json.Result);
```

Comment: but i want the value to be submitted as if it is posted using a form , such as create or edit forms.. i do not want to send the parameter as a query string ,, for security reasons ...

Comment: thanks a lot for the edit,,,and regarding the Authorization header ,, can i still pass it using " wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);" and receive it on the action method by "Request.Headers.Get("Authorization");"  same as i were doing using DownloadStringTaskAsycn ?

Comment: Yes you can still use `wc.Headers.Add(...)`; sorry copy-and-paste issue.

Answer (score 0):

The return value from `UploadStringTaskAsync` is `Task<string>`.  You will need to either await the returned task, add a continuation, or block the thread to wait for the result to be returned.

Blocking method:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var url = currentURL+ "home/scanserver";
    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
    var json = wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(url, "FQDN=allscan").Result;
}
```

Using await (must be inside a method marked as async):

```
string json;
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var url = currentURL + "home/scanserver";
    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
    json = await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(url, "FQDN=allscan");
}
```

Comment: but i want the value to be submitted as if it is posted using a form , such as create or edit forms.. i do not want to send the parameter as a query string ,, for security reasons .

Answer (score 0):

For a simple query param, you can do as @Richard has said

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var url = currentURL+ "home/scanserver?FQDN=allscan";
    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
    var json =wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(url, "");
}
```

Or, if you want to send a long string, or a complex object `MyObject` then you can do like

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var url = currentURL+ "home/scanserver";
    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    //here you can also pass a json serialized complex object
    var json =wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(url, "{FQDN:'allscan'}"); 
}
```

I'm assuming here, that your api method looks like

```
public void scanserver(string FQDN) //OR (MyClass myObject)
{
    //do something with token and FQDN 
    //OR use your complex object - myObject
}
```